# if $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is holomorphic and $\Omega$ is simply connected, show there is a holomorphic function $g^2 = f$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms

I am making exercises to prepare for my exam and came across this one

> Suppose $\Omega$ is simply connected and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is holomorphic. Show that there is a holomorphic function $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ such that
> $$g^2 = f.$$
> [$g$ is a holomorphic branch of the square root of $f$, and we can write $g$ as $g = f^{1/2}$.

I am a bit stuck on how I am supposed to solve this question. I thought that branches are connected to the complex logarithm, also the theorems in my book that use that $\Omega$ is simply connected use the complex logarithm aswell.

But I am not sure on how I could use the logarithm or the exponentials in this question since I want to get the square root of the function.

Comment: **Hint :** If you have a $\log$, you have also $\exp \left( \dfrac{1}{2}\log\right)$...

Comment: If I use the theore that says 'If f is nowhere vanishhing holomorphic function in a simply connected region $\Omega$, then there exists a holomorphic function $h$ on $\Omega$ st $f(z) = e^{h(z)}$. If I let $h = 2 log(g(z))$ then I would get $g^2 = f$ but I don't think I can use the theorem like that since I just assigned $g$ a value and am not sure if thats allowed.

Comment: You misunderstood what I am saying : once you have such an $h$, you can define $g = \exp \left( \dfrac{1}{2} h\right)$, and check that $g^2 = f$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to prove that logarithms exist, that is, you can find some $h$ with $\exp h = f$. Once you get such $h$, it is clear that $\exp\left(\frac 1 2 h\right)$ will be a square root of $f$.

To find $h$, notice that the equation $\exp h = f$ implies that $\exp h\cdot h' = f'$ which tells you that $h' = f'/f$. The last equation makes sense because $f$ is non-vanishing (per your hypothesis).

Thus, finding logarithms is equivalent to proving that $f'/f$ has a primitive in your simply connected domain $\Omega$. Of course, this is true, since you can pick a point $z_0\in \Omega$ and set

$$h(z) = \int_{z_0}^z \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw.$$

where we integrate along any path $\gamma: z_0\to z$. This is well defined because $\Omega$ is simply connected and $f'/f$ is analytic. Checking that $h'(z) = f'(z)/ f(z)$ is a direct computation.

Comment: Do we have to specify $h$? As in theroem "If f is nowhere vanishhing holomorphic function in a simply connected region $Ω$, then there exists a holomorphic function $ℎ$ on $Ω$ st $()=^{ℎ()}$" says such a $h$ exists. Can I then say let $g = 1/2 h$, since $h$ is holomorphic, that this means that $g$ is holomorphic? Why do I have to 'find $h$' and do the calculations you did?

Comment: @fieke_2000 They're essentially proving the theorem that such $h$ exists. If you already proved it, you don't need to construct $h$ again.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you both!